# 200 Jquery server request with no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

My goal is to print a string from a rendered html page.

I'm using the code below to fetch body content from a url:

```
    var proxy = "http://myproxyname.pythonanywhere.com/response?userinput=google"

    $.ajax({
        url: proxy,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#display').text(data);
        }
    })
}
```

I'm using this because the API i'm working with require `Allow cross origin`, actually, I setup a little flask app that do the job for me. I'm able to print html of some urls I tested with this function so it's working but for the one I'm using it's 200 OK but empty response.

Can someone explain why I'm not receiving the html content? Is there a special parameters with Jquery? Should I enable cross-origin in my flask app?

My last question is how to make the request but telling Javascript not to take into account headers?

**Update:**

When I make the request manually from the console I get a response but unable to print it on the page `cause = other`. When I click on the button to make the request it throw `cause = JS` and there's no response inside.

**Update 2:**

When I receive a valid response in the console, I only see this changes in request headers:

> Pragma     "no-cache"
>
> Cache-Control  "no-cache"

There's a way I can add it directly to the JS code?

**Update 3:**

My proxy code using Python (Flask):

```
@app.route('/response')
def response():

    url = 'http://longstringurlapi.com'
    data = str(request.args.get( "userinput" , None ))
    jsoninput = json.dumps(data)

    r = requests.post(url ,data=jsoninput)
    response = r.text

    return render_template('results.html', response=response, data=data)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: so, your proxy sometimes succeeds in getting the html from a cross origin site and sometimes it doesn't get anything, is that what you're saying? If so, the issue is with whatever `http://myproxyname.pythonanywhere.com/` ... having said that, can you see the HTML in the response of the request in the browser developer tools **network** tab?

Comment: The proxy is working correctly, what I've done is clicked network tab then Edit and resend, I changed anything but this time received a valid response with full html.. @JaromandaX After request what changed is cause and size.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the related proxy code?

Comment: Also, please ask each of your questions separately on SO. It keeps each Q&A more specific and each one can be more easily answered by different people that way.

Comment: Right, you seem to have ignored what I asked ... in your code, you make a request ... what can you see in the developer tools network tab for that request ... is there a response with all the response you expect? you can't very well edit and resend for your code to work, can you, so that is meaningless information ... also ... I have no idea what/where cause=other vs cause=js means or how it is relevant

Comment: I answered your question, the proxy is working. I can see the response if I visit the url directly from my browser, with js it don't seems to work. My goal is to print a simple string, like web scraping.. @JaromandaX

Comment: visiting the URL directly is not the same as fetching the URL in code ... that's why I'm asking if, when you fetch the URL in code, does the browser developer network tab show you are getting the response you are expecting - do you know what the developer tools network tab is? do you know how to see what is being received as a response? Sorry if the question is too hard for you to answer

Comment: I know what is a valid response from a server, actually there's no response. If you have 'lorem ipsum' in a page how can you print this string on another page with JS? Easier said than done? @JaromandaX

Comment: `Easier said than done?` quite simple if your proxy did its job

Comment: @JaromandaX Update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896336/js-unable-to-retrieve-data-from-a-custom-flask-api